# How can one extract all dependent bundles of a specific bundle in a tycho build?

Tags: tycho, p2

I have a scenario that requires me to deploy a Java application that does **not** use OSGI, but its underlying set of Java archives must still come from well-defined P2 repositories. I need a trick that enables me to gather all dependent bundles of the bundle that contains the Java class that holds the main method. This process should be automated, ideally in Tycho.

In Eclipse there is a user interface operation "Export as ... Runnable JAR" that yields a similar result. I assume that P2 will have features to do this somehow. Maybe I could use a modified product installation?

Comment: A maven-assembly-plugin based approach may also work. Tycho injects p2 and intra-reactor dependencies as "system" respectively "provided" scope dependencies into the Maven model, so you should be able to assemble them with a descriptor similar to the [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) descriptor. Never tried this myself though. I'd be interested in a working example.

Comment: The recommended approach works well. I will update the question with an answer and example snippet once finished. However, I am now trying to restrict the extraction by cutting out the dependencies on the eclipse.org bundles. How would I use the <excludes> element to get all of that group? Just a match on groupId org.eclipse?

Comment: A simple match of the type org.eclipse.* or eclipse.org:* in the <excludes> list does not seem to work. How does tycho map the groupId field when injecting bundles from P2?